# Babel Build Script Is Not Copying Files To Folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, babeljs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app to create a library. My build script is not doing anything when it should copying everything from `src/lib` to `dist`. I have the latest `@babel/cli` installed.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

It just says `Done in 0.14s` and does not actually copy anything.

Also, should I be using rollup instead? And how should I be configuring my babel for performance and compatibility (ex: ES5=>ES6)?

Answer (score 0):

Babel is part of the built-in configuration of create-react-app, so you don't need to install babel-cli or use babel directly. The `build` script should simply be `{ "build": "react-scripts build" }`